# Crashes not being received by Firebase/Crashlytics

Tags: swift, firebase, crashlytics

I'm forcing a crash, via a button, and Firebase/Crashlytics doesn't seem to pic it up.

Some background on my app.

My app has two App IDs, one for enterprise to be used internally and one for the app store. A script is triggered when a build is triggered, so that the right GoogleService-Info.plist is being used for the build. The enterprise version works fine, dsyms upload and crashes are received. The app store is missing the dsym and the crashes wont go through.

I make the build, stop the debugger, run the app on 4G, to cut out the company wifi which may have a firewall blocking the request

```
[Crashlytics] Version 3.10.5 (130)
[Fabric] [Fabric +with] called multiple times. Only the first call is honored, please pass all kits you wish to initialize
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id '18357d12a8ce415584520b8f889d2776' for submission
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
...
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] completed submission of /path/to/app/file.multipartmime
[Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful
```

As an aside, it said that I'm missing the dSYM, I uploaded the dsym and it still says I need to up load it.

Update:

Mike noted that the log with

```
[Fabric] [Fabric +with] called multiple times. Only the first call is honored, please pass all kits you wish to initialize
```

Looked like trouble

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = false
//Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])  // this was causing that line to appear
```

So here's what the log looks like now after I plug in to the debugger after a crash.

Note: I changed the settings for the logging to .notice and for fabric debug is set to true, along with the argument FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled to YES

```
[Crashlytics] Version 3.10.5 (130)
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id 'cdece9d5d08e4caea8fcb1b1aa0e87da' for submission
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting async /path.multipartmime
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports:Event] Sending event.
[Crashlytics:Crash] Unable to read identifier at path /path
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Unable to remove a processing item
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id '(null)' for submission
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting async path.multipartmime
4.8.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40009000 started
4.8.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see URL to some place)
[Fabric] settings downloaded successfully
[Fabric] Settings are available for consumption
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] completed submission of /path/770D4E72-67E0-4763-9FAA-687C0701A445.multipartmime
[Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] completed submission of /path.multipartmime
[Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful
```

It said I didn't enable logging though I did. Weird, but no biggie.

Unfortunately still the console isn't picking up the crashes, and now that I go back to the dSYMs there were 4 entries when there were only 2 before.

Note: The crash free users stats has changed, and under the missing dSYMs it shows the crashes, but there are no issues showing up.

**Here's the dSYMs**
[image]

**And here's the dashboard**
[image]

Comment: are you uploading the dsym you downloaded from itunes connect? apple recompiles a new dsym from the binary you upload, instead of directly using the original one

Comment: I didn't know that. Let me try that. Thanks.

Comment: Do tell us if it works, so that I can write a proper answer. Thanks

Comment: I had bitcode disabled, because it was causing the app to crash in an earlier version of XCode. So it's not possible for me to download the dSym. With that being said, the dSym that I have should work right?

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. This warning makes me pause - [Fabric] [Fabric +with] called multiple times. Only the first call is honored, please pass all kits you wish to initialize. What's your init look like?

Comment: Alright Mike, I'll update my description

Comment: Actually I think I'm misunderstanding things, with how the kits are supposed to initialized. Am I supposed to have Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])? I'm going to check the documentation.

Comment: Alright I looked over at https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-from-crash-reporting, and correct me if I'm wrong, Firebase Crashlytics SDK should automatically initialize Crashlytics right?

Comment: Great, with the update info, you're missing the dSYM need to process the crashes.  Use mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == <UUID>" with the UUIDs of the missing dSYMs to find and upload them so the crashes can be processed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I added a script to upload the dSym and manually uploaded it. I was only able to find one of the dSyms. Something to note, on the dSym it says it's an older version for some reason, even though I cracked open the .APP folder and saw a different version :/ I'll wait a few minutes to see if the dash board updates.

Comment: It to have worked! Now I want to check that the scripts alone will do the job, I don't want to manually upload them all the time, so I generated some crashes. We'll see how that turns out. Thanks.

Comment: Cool it worked, I just needed to add the script to the build phase. Do you want me to add the answer or do you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The things I did to fix this:

1. Remove Fabric keys, this only applies if you previously had Fabric/Crashlytics installed.
   [image: plist screenshot]
2. Remove this line

   ```
   Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
   ```

   if you see this in your console

> [Fabric] [Fabric +with] called multiple times. Only the first call is honored, please pass all kits you wish to initialize

3. Finally if your crashes/dSYM doesn't appear add this as a run script phase in your build phases. I named the phase "Upload dSYM"

   ```
   "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
   ```

   I confirmed the upload was successful by going to the build log, finding "Run custom shell script 'Upload dSYM' expanding it to show the status. It should say something similar to this for the each architecture you're building for.

> 2018-07-19 18:38:15.630 upload-symbols[42776:1122351] Successfully submitted symbols for architecture arm64 with UUID 011bb8b8c270398292fac15e0fa117ed in dSYM: /path/YourApp.app.dSYM

Comment: This solution appears to be for Crashlytics rather than Firebase integrated Crashlytics. Can you confirm?

Comment: The script showing me an error. I have wright script in 1 line. Anything wrong in this?

Comment: @Native_Mobile_Arch_Dev Sorry for the late response, the project went through many phases, it may have had the old Crashlytics at one point in time. But in the end after these changes, it was working for current version of Crashlytics on Firebase.

Comment: Work now. There was a small correction in .plist path at my end.

Answer (score 4):

**What Didn't Work**

Xcode 9.4.1  |  iOS 11  |  Swift 4

I wasn't getting crashes despite trying a number of things that didn't work:

1. Forcing a crash via `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()` after initializing Crashlytics in `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`
2. Adding the script mentioned in another answer `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"`
3. Waiting 5 min between tests (a few times)
4. Forcing a crash a different way, like force unwrapping a nil var.
5. Running the app on a real device, both debugging through xCode and running while unplugged.

I could see this in the console...

> 2018-09-13 17:58:01.893028-0500 Diem[8715:8252505] [Crashlytics] Version 3.10.7 (130)

...so it seemed like Crashlytics was being initialized, but still nothing was showing up in the FB Crashlytics console.

**What Fixed It**

In the Firebase docs, it shows an example of creating UI, adding a crash button.  I assumed adding the UI was a trivial piece, which it is.  However, it seems that Crashlytics doesn't fully initialize until some point after `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`, which wasn't clear from the docs.

**I moved the line that forces a crash into my main view controller's `viewDidLoad()` and the crash showed up almost immediately in the Crashlytics dashboard.**

Answer (score -1):

Crashlytics is having an outage, see [Status](https://status.firebase.google.com/) here.

Comment: That's odd, I've been getting crashes from my other app.

Comment: Yeah, weird... maybe a cache mechanism was working instead? Hope it gets fixed soon to verify if you still have the issue

Comment: I had it working yesterday, and I made it crash recently and now it won't pop up in the console. :/