# Fabric with called multiple times

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, crashlytics

After integration flutter IOS with firebase crashlytics from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios) and run that issue show in console

> [Fabric] [Fabric +with] called multiple times. Only the first call is honored, please pass all kits you wish to initialize

Comment: I am wondering if you have checked this answer right in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51450286/8342742)?

Answer (score 0):

Firebaser here --

We see this often happen for apps that have migrated from Fabric to Firebase, and are calling both `Fabric.with` and `FirebaseApp.configure()`. If you're following the instructions from that doc, you should be removing any `Fabric.with` call you may be making.

These two calls might also not be right next to each other in your code, so make sure you only have one of either of these anywhere in your codebase.

Comment: I don't have any `Fabric.with` calls. I'm only following these instructions: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics#use-the-plugin

Comment: I believe a new version of https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics#use-the-plugin was just released - could you check if this helps?